# How to push an array of objects into an array in mongoose with one call?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to push multiple values into an array in mongoose using one call. I tried doing it using a smaller array but the array is getting inserted as a sub-array.

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        values: [Number]
});

var Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
Kitten.update({name: 'fluffy'},{$push: {values:[2,3]}},{upsert:true},function(err){
        if(err){
                console.log(err);
        }else{
                console.log("Successfully added");
        }
});
```

The result of the calling the above code thrice gives the below result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502b0e807809d79e84403606"), "name" : "fluffy", "values" : [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3 ] ] }
```

Whereas what I want is something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502b0e807809d79e84403606"), "name" : "fluffy", "values" : [ 2, 3 ,2 ,3, 2, 3] }
```

Another thing I noticed was that the type in the array (values) is specified as Number, then wouldnt the 'strict' option ensure that anything other than Numbers are not inserted ? In this case another array is being allowed to be inserted.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**(Dec-2014 update)** Since MongoDB2.4 you should use:

```
Kitten.update({name: 'fluffy'}, {$push: {values: {$each: [2,3]}}}, {upsert:true}, function(err){
        if(err){
                console.log(err);
        }else{
                console.log("Successfully added");
        }
});
```

Comment: If no doc with `{name: "fluffy"}` in it exists, does `{upsert: true}` create it?; also, if I do `{upsert: true, new: true}`, can I do function(err, result) {} and get in result all of the documents that were created/updated?

Answer (score 41):

***Deprecated*** see other solution below using $push $each

Your example is close, but you want [$pushAll](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) rather than [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to have each value added separately (rather than pushing another array onto the `values` array):

```
var Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
Kitten.update({name: 'fluffy'},{$pushAll: {values:[2,3]}},{upsert:true},function(err){
        if(err){
                console.log(err);
        }else{
                console.log("Successfully added");
        }
});
```

Comment: NB: you may also want to look at [$addToSet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating/#Updating-%24addToSetand%24each), which can be used to only add values to an array if they aren't there already.

Comment: Thanks Stennie! That works. I missed this part in the documentation.

Comment: @Stennie this only works for individual elements, not for concatenating arrays.

Comment: @Tom concatenating arrays can be done with $addToSet together with [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#each-modifier).

Answer (score 5):

Or use the $each modifier with $addToSet:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#each-modifier

> ```
> // Existing tags array
> { _id: 2, item: "cable", tags: [ "electronics", "supplies" ] }
>
> // Add "camera" and "accessories" to it
> db.inventory.update(
>    { _id: 2 },
>    { $addToSet: { tags: { $each: [ "camera", "accessories" ] } } }
>  )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the updated [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) doesn't support `$pushAll`. It seems to have been deprecated.
Now the good choice is to use the combination of `$push` & `$each`

an example:

```js
//User schema: {uid: String, transaction: [objects] }
const filter = {"uid": uid};
const update = {
        $push: {
            transactions: {$each: dataarr}
        }
    }
User.updateOne(filter, update, {upsert:true}, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

pass `{upsert: true}` at options to insert if the filter returns false.